# In addtion to email subject and body, can we pass email header via DocuSign API?

Tags: email, docusignapi

I'm using AnswerModules Content Script in OpenText Content Server to make DocuSign API calls and send remote signing emails. With docusign.createEnvelopeAndSend(null, envDef), I'm able to send the envelope definition which has document to be signed, recipient details, email subject and email body. We've multiple scenarios wherein different email body & subject is used according to document category. Now we've a new requirement to specify the email header as well. Is it possible to achieve this?

E.g.
I'm sending a billing document to user for signing which should have the following details:
email subject - "Monthly Invoice"
email header - "Review and Sign your invoice for June,2020"
email body - "This would be some text from Business for Customers"

When I define an envelope i've the String variables for emailSubject & emailBody that I can pass by a DocuSign API call but there's no such emailHeader variable to hold some String.

Basically need to understand if there's a way to use some variable text in the remote signing process?

Comment: Please edit and update your question to give more details on exactly what you mean by `the email header`. Emails have many headers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "header".
I would start by reviewing this document - https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-email-resource-file-v1-1
which is a guide on all customization you can make.
But let me give two options for header.
Header in the technological sense, is not allowed. That part of the SMTP message is set by DocuSign and you cannot modify it.
Header in the visual sense, meaning something at the top of the page is possible by customizing the HTML.